# Funcionamiento de dynos en Heroku

Tags: angularjs, ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment

- ¿Cómo funcionan las dynos de Heroku?
- ¿Puedo tener mas de una?

Por ahora tengo

```
web: node app.js  --> levanta la aplicación de Angular
worker: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb --> Rails API
```

Hasta ahí me funciona todo bien, me levanta la aplicacion de angular y la api de rails.

Pero cuando hago una llamada desde Angular a la API, me da un **error 404**. La llamada `/api/authenticate` es dirigida a web1 y no a la API.

No se si está mal conceptualmente que ponga en web a angular y en worker a la api.

Comment: _Rails_ debe estar en un _dyno_ configurado como **_web_**, de lo contrario no podrás procesar peticiones _HTTP_. Checa [este link](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#dyno-configurations) de _Heroku_ con el detalle (en inglés).

Comment: Gracias! y en que dyno corro node app.js? Puedo agregar más?

Comment: ¿Qué proceso seguiste para hacer el _deploy_ a Heroku?, ¿Instalaste los buildpacks adecuados? Checa [este link](https://www.google.com.mx/amp/s/blogstephenarifin.wordpress.com/2017/01/09/angular-2-and-ruby-on-rails-on-heroku/amp/) (también en inglés) con un ejemplo de deploy a Heroku.

Comment: Seguí tu tutorial, y habia seguido uno parecido pero no me resulto. Me levantan la api pero no la aplicacion de angular.

Comment: Listo!! Gracias Gerry, el segundo tutorial me sirvió. Mi problema era que no estoy usando **angular-cli**. Modifiqué el **package.json** para que haga `grunt build` y `grunt serve`. Con eso me funcionó

Comment: Excelente! Valdría la pena que respondas tu pregunta con lo que hiciste para resolver el problema; y acepta lesa respuesta para que futuros programadores que tengan el mismo problema puedan encontrar ayuda.